How to optimise a leaflet page load time
This is a question in direct follow-up to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56720672/7752303
The issue is this: we have a leaflet page which is slow to load up and thus scores dramatically low in Google performance scores
What would be the best way to improve this score, assuming we want to try the approach proposed in the above link i.e. initially display a "skeleton" of the map and when the actual leaflet map is loaded, swap it in.
I'm using react in this case but any valid suggestions will work and I can adapt them to react as needed.
